# Convert few strings to one string

Tags: xml, batch-file, text-extraction

I have many XML files with many different events. Any event have some tags:

```
<v8e:Event>
    <v8e:Level>Information</v8e:Level>
    <v8e:Date>2015-12-22T16:18:17</v8e:Date>
    <v8e:ApplicationName>1CV8</v8e:ApplicationName>
</v8e:Event>
<v8e:Event>
    <v8e:Level>Information</v8e:Level>
    <v8e:Date>2015-12-23T16:18:17</v8e:Date>
    <v8e:ApplicationName>1CV28</v8e:ApplicationName>
</v8e:Event>
```

I want convert this stricture for this:

```
Information, 2015-12-22T16:18:17, 1CV8
Information, 2015-12-23T16:18:17, 1CV28
```

I know how remove XML tags, but I not don't know how concatenate different string in one.

@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

```
(for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /I /L "<v8e:Level> <v8e:Date> <v8e:ApplicationName>" *.xml') do (
   set "line=%%a"
   set "line=!line:*<v8e:Level>=!"
   set "line=!line:*<v8e:Date>=!"
   set "line=!line:*<v8e:ApplicationName>=!"
   for /F "delims=<" %%b in ("!line!") do echo %%b
)) > 111.txt
```

As reuslt I have:

```
Information
2015-12-22T16:18:17
1CV8
Information
2015-12-23T16:18:17
1CV28
```

And I also want name of output file same like input file.
Maybe someone can halp me to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "output="
set "fields=0"
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /I /L "<v8e:Level> <v8e:Date> <v8e:ApplicationName>" *.xml') do (
   set "line=%%a"
   set "line=!line:*<v8e:Level>=!"
   set "line=!line:*<v8e:Date>=!"
   set "line=!line:*<v8e:ApplicationName>=!"
   for /F "delims=<" %%b in ("!line!") do set "line=%%b"
   set "output=!output!!line!, "
   set /A fields+=1
   if !fields! equ 3 (
      set "file=%%a"
      for /F "delims=:" %%b in ("!file!") do echo !output:~0,-2!>> "%%~Nb.txt"
      set "output="
      set "fields=0"
   )
)
```

However, this is the way I would do it:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%f in (*.xml) do (

   set "output="
   set "fields=0"
   (for /F "tokens=3 delims=<>" %%a in ('findstr /I /L "<v8e:Level> <v8e:Date> <v8e:ApplicationName>" "%%f"') do (
      set "output=!output!%%a, "
      set /A fields+=1
      if !fields! equ 3 (
         echo !output:~0,-2!
         set "output="
         set "fields=0"
      )
   )) > "%%~Nf.txt"

)
```

Comment: If I want change number of my filed? For exampe add extra 7 filed: <v8e:Level> <v8e:Date> <v8e:ApplicationName> <v8e:ApplicationPresentation> <v8e:EventPresentation> <v8e:UserName> <v8e:Computer> <v8e:TransactionStatus> <v8e:ServerName> <v8e:Port>, what Ialso should change in your script? And what I should do if some field will be empty? For example <v8e:Event>
    <v8e:Level>Information</v8e:Level>
    <v8e:Date>2015-12-23T16:18:17</v8e:Date>
    <v8e:ApplicationName>
</v8e:Event>

Comment: Add the extra 7 fields: <v8e:Level> <v8e:Date> <v8e:ApplicationName> <v8e:ApplicationPresentation> <v8e:EventPresentation> <v8e:UserName> <v8e:Computer> <v8e:TransactionStatus> <v8e:ServerName> <v8e:Port> and add a 7 to the 3 fields. If some field is empty you may use tokens=2,3 instead just 3 and if "%%b" neq "" ( set "output=!output!%%b, " ) else ( set "output=!output!empty, " ) instead just set "output=!output!%%a, "